# Knockout Rat Phenotype Database?

Tags: genetics

Is there a database where I might list the phenotype of a certain rat knockout and/or search for other similar phenotypes?

There is a [International Mouse Phenotyping Consortium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mouse_Phenotyping_Consortium), which has the goal of characterizing the phenotypical changes of homozygous knockouts for each of the 20,000 genes in the isogenic mouse line C57BL/6.  The [International Knockout Mouse Consortium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Knockout_Mouse_Consortium) is responsible for creating the knockouts and the two consortiums work together closely.

There is also a Knockout Rat Consortium, but I haven't found a Phenotype Change database for rats.

Answer (score 1):

Opinion:

the Jackson laboratory

http://jaxmice.jax.org/

Is the industry leader in transgenic mouse production. Their list of mouse strains is almost a db in itself but currently no db exists that I'm aware of. I take it your looking for something similar to what's available for c elegans:

http://www.celeganskoconsortium.omrf.org/